# Native c# functions to desirabilia an xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a string like:

```
&lt;Cols&gt;&lt;Col idx=&quot;C1&quot; Name=&quot;Speed&quot; Type=&quot;Int&quot; /&gt;&lt;Col idx=&quot;C2&quot; Name=&quot;Time&quot; Type=&quot;Decimal&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Cols&gt;
```

that I need to convert to an XDocument:

the resulting xml is:

```
<Cols>
    <Col idx="C1" Name="Speed" Type="Int" />
    <Col idx="C2" Name="Time" Type="Decimal" />
</Cols>
```

I can do it with a simple replace logic and then load it but is there any build in functions for that in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.WebUtility` or `System.Web.HttpUtility`

```
string s = "&lt;Cols&gt;&lt;Col idx=&quot;C1&quot; Name=&quot;Speed&quot; Type=&quot;Int&quot; /&gt;&lt;Col idx=&quot;C2&quot; Name=&quot;Time&quot; Type=&quot;Decimal&quot; /&gt;&lt;/Cols&gt;";
var xml = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s); //OR HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
var xDcoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```